# Flutter SizedBox vs LimitedBox

Tags: flutter, dart

I have read docs for both `SizedBox` and `LimitedBox`, and didn't find any practical difference between the two.

Can anyone give an example when one may fail and other work?

Comment: .. vs ConstrainedBox vs FittedBox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So what I have found is, `LimitedBox` is only usable when the child is given unconstrained `width/height` by its parent.

And `SizedBox` simply creates a box with given `width/height` and doesn't allow child to go beyond given dimensions.

---

Example: (`LimitedBox`)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: LimitedBox(
      maxHeight: 50, // no impact because it's child `Text` width/height isn't unconstrained
      child: Text(
        "A",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Example (`SizedBox`)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SizedBox(
      height: 50, // has impact, it won't let Text to be of more than 50 logical pixels high
      child: Text(
        "A",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Note: If anyone has better answer, I am happy to accept theirs.

Comment: This answer just pointed out what "not to do" but faield to give a solution to the problem.

Comment: also SizedBox not only restricts child to go beyond but also restricts to go below given dimensions. Another thing to note is that LimitedBox gives maxHeight/maxWidth and SizedBox gives exact height/width

Answer (score 3):

**LimitBox:**

> LimitBox works only when it's size is unconstrained If this widget's
> maximum width is unconstrained then its child's width is limited to
> [maxWidth].  Similarly, if this widget's maximum height is
> unconstrained then its child's height is limited to [maxHeight].

**Example:**

```
Center(
    child: LimitedBox(
        maxWidth: 50,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 20,
          height: 100,
        )
    ),
  ),
```

Output:

This restricts `Container` Widget with a max-width as 50 but it's going to show widget till container width which is 20.

[image]

**SizeBox:**

> It comes with fixed sizes that restrict its child to render on the
> limited area.  If either the width or height is null, this widget will
> try to size itself to match the child's size in that dimension. If the
> child's size depends on the size of its parent, the height and width
> must be provided.

**Example:**

```
Center(
        child: SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 20,
              height: 100,
            )
        ),
      ),
```

Output:

This will also behave like `LimitedBox` but the only difference here `Container` will be rendered till width 50 of `SizeBox`, it will not consider it's own width which is 20 and drawn till the parent widget.

[image]

Comment: in your example if LimitedBox has no effect why to use it?

Comment: LimitBox, allows its child to grow as much as possible, but not more hen max width and max height of LimitBox

Answer (score 2):

`LimitedBox` is a `SizedBox` unless the parent widget imposes a constraint.

### From Doc

> A box that limits its size only when it's unconstrained.

### Reference

[Flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LimitedBox-class.html)

Comment: Thanks I have also read that line, my main question was "Example when one fails and other work'.

Comment: this is not correct read the answer from @user6274128

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone give an example when one may fail and other work?

They'll both *work*, but they'll do different things.  The example from [the `LimitedBox` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LimitedBox-class.html) says:

> This is useful when composing widgets that normally try to match their parents' size, so that they behave reasonably in lists.

Imagine that you are creating a reusable widget and don't have control over where it's used.  You could use a `SizedBox`, but then your widget will *always* have the specified size, even if its size is already constrained by a parent widget.

Comment: Thanks james but this line doesn't make any sense `This is useful when composing widgets that normally try to match their parents' size, so that they behave reasonably in lists.` -- Because if I use `LimitedBox` in `SizedBox.expand` it doesn't limit the height of child placed inside `LimitedBox` say a `Container`. Widget tree: `SizedBox.expand - LimitedBox(maxHeight: 100) - Container(height: 200)` you an see Container expands doesn't obey `100` contraint.